# Why for loop only save the last file in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

When I choose two images in my template, the save method always save the last image selected  but I don't understand what it is happens.

this is my view:

```
class imgcreate(CreateView):
    model = Archivos
    template_name = 'img.html'
    form_class = imgForm
    success_url =  reverse_lazy('BackEnd:unidades')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('imagen')
        if form.is_valid():
            a = 0
            for imagen in files:
                a = a+1
                img = form.save(commit=False)
                img.id_unidad = 1
                img.tipo_archivo = 1
                img.nombre_archivo ='hhh'+ str(a) 

                img.save()
            print(a);


            return self.form_valid(form)

        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

print always returns the name of the image with 2 that mean  only the last image is saved

Comment: Huh?  Your `print (a)` statement is outside the loop.  So it will ways print the length of `files`.  Move it inside the loop, and it will print 1, 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
if request.method=="POST":
    form = PlanfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        files = request.FILES.getlist('large_img')

        for a_file in files:
            instance = Planfile(
            plan_id = 1, #the foreign key
            large_img=a_file
            )
            instance.save()
        return HttpResponse("success!")
else:
   ...
```